# How to show a progress dialog automatically when an interface's method called on Android?

Tags: android, interface, progressdialog

I have an interface ServerListener with these three basic methods

```
public interface ServerListener {

void onSuccess();
void onProgress();
void onFailed(String error);
```

}

I am using this method every time when I want to get some results from the server and showing a progress dialog to the user on onProgress() method like this:

```
  mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mUserSetupViewModel.onIdentityUploadClicked(fileName, data.getData(), new ServerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress() {
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailed(String error) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
```

How can I attach the progress dialog with the interface so that I don't have to write code for progress dialog manually every time when I am dealing with the server on any activity or fragment on the app.
I just want to init the listener and want to automatically show progress dialog and dismiss based on events.

Comment: You have to write code at-least once.  `ProgressDialog` is an UI component So to make it make it available to each Fragment or Activity you can have a Base class ie. `BaseActivity` or `BaseFragment` and have two methods for show and hide progress.

Comment: Also `ProgressDialog` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog) so you might wanna create a Custom dialog.

Comment: thanks, @ADM ..for your answer. so is there any other workaround to achieve something like this without writing same code every time...
And I am not using deprecated progressdialog..i have made a custom dialog extending AlertDialog ..just named it same ...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a subclass of `Activity` class, and implement the `ServerListener` there. and then extends your real activity from that sub class.

```java
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServerListener {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onProgress() {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }


    @Override
    public void onFailed(String error) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    
}
```

```java
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mUserSetupViewModel.onIdentityUploadClicked(fileName, data.getData(), this);
    }

}
```